# ajax post always send null parameter my controller

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, actionresult

I tried to start new view via parameter, but ajax post method couldn't pass parameter to the controller. Controller parameter always seen Null.

**Index.schtml**: I triggered in  element in html also passing controller and action via `Url.Action` inside the element. Then run the script:

```
function getPList(target)
{
    var Pdata = JSON.stringify({
         'sNo': "88888888"
    });
    $ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: target,
        data: Pdata,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("Response Data ↓");
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult PListIndex(String sNo)
{
     return View(sNo);
}
```

How to pass controller parameter ?

Comment: try removing `dataType: 'json', contentType: 'application/json',` after the edit from @xrodas answer

Comment: My Onclick event is;  return "<td><a href='@Url.Action("MyListIndex","MyOrders")' onclick='getPList(this.href)'  style='color:#000; text-decoration: underline;'> " + data + "</a></td>";  but issue is, go twice to controller and second call's  give me parameter null , How can I prevent double call controller?

Comment: Because you have `href` defined!! I don't see this code in your question. Please post the relevant html code and onclick handler to understand this better.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller variable is called sNo, but you are passing a variable in js called pNo. They should have the same name.

Also try to pass data like this:

```
 $ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: target,
        data: { sNo: "888888" },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("Response Data ↓");
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```